# How to recognize spaces vs tab button in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I had actually asked for help regarding the click of the tag button to be places in the search field. That part is done. But I noticed that I cannot search for more than 2 things in one tag.

For instance: When a user wants to search the words 'Bank Loan' as one query. It will return like so: [image]

So to avoid this, I thought of having the tag completion on 'tab' rather than space. How would I accomplish this? I have a [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/YEr6m/18/) to show what I mean.

```
var $input = $('#search'),
    $tagInput = $('.tag-input');

$input.bind('input', function() {
    var inputValues = $input.val().trim().split(' ');
    console.log(inputValues);
    $tagInput.html('');
    if ($input.val().trim().length > 0) {
        for (var i in inputValues) {
            $tagInput.append('<a>' + inputValues[i] + '</a>');
        }
    }
    $input.width($tagInput.width());
});

$('.keywords .tag').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    $input.val(($input.val() + ' ' + $this.text().trim()).trim());
    $input.trigger('input');
});
```

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Please don't. Tab is the key to move from one field to the next, you will break its known useage and kittens will die. A comma would be the most expected separator.

Comment: @popnoodles I can't have kittens dying. How would I go about having the query recognize commas?

Comment: Your fiddle is a bit weird - I don't see any javascript or HTML, only the output. //edit strange, I had to log in to see the code.

Comment: If you replace the space in the split with a comma that will work on commas, but the display is messed up because it's been written to be the size of a space, trying to hide one thing on another which is a bit crazy

Comment: @ithcy jsfiddle has been doing that recently

Comment: I would personally encourage the users to use a dash between words when they want to input a search term group, which you should later (before searching) replace with single space(s) `bank-loan`,`apple` etc.

Comment: Just remembered how [**delicious**](https://delicious.com) made it in its new interface. Did you check it?

Answer (score 0):

Most libraries that do this will allow you to enclose your keywords in quotes to make it a keyphrase.